# Help On Programming .htaccess to redirect to controller

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I need to convert the following where website url that user inputs ,

var1 is a wildcard set by user to login to his account details.

http://var1.domain.com/var2/var3
redirect to:
http://domain.com/master5.php?uid=var1&wid=var2&camid=var3

and another rule i need is

var1.domain.com/var2/
redirect to:
domain.com/master5.php?uid=var1&wid=var2

if possible I need to cloak them too so user actually only see
var1.domain.com/var2/var3

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect/rewrite help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432296/htaccess-redirect-rewrite-help-needed)

Comment: i dont think it is possible without registering all var1 domains in your dns records

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at preg expressions, but what you're looking for is something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.domain\.com/.*/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\..*/(.*)/(.*)$ master5.php?uid=$1&wid=$2&camid=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.domain\.com/.*/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\..*/(.*)/$ master5.php?uid=$1&wid=$2
```

The conidition determines whether the rule should run, and the rule says how to translate the URL provided into the actual URL you wish to execute. You may wish to try and refine the preg into precisely what you want using something like http://regextester.com/ to fine tune it.

Edit: Note, you must have setup your DNS entry for *.domain.com rather than for www.domain.com otherwise no subdomains will be passed through to your server anyway.

Comment: I got it working but when I tried haha.domain.com the subdomain variable does not pass through :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but the last rule does not pass the subdomain variable when I enter http://something.domain.com

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://www.domain.com/master5.php?username=%2&$1&$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/master5.php?username=%2&$1&$2

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/profile.php?username=%2 [L]